# C++ Move Assignment Operator - this != &that check

Tags: c++

A simple question which probably doesn't require much explanation, only an example.

Consider a move assignment operator:

```
myclass& operator=(myclass&& c)
{
    if(this != &c)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Is it sensible to include the `if(this != &c)` check? (For a **move** assignment operator.) If so [or so not], why?

Comment: Did you mean `myclass& operator=(myclass&& c)`

Comment: Yes, apologies, that is exactly what I mean